# Use Bootswatch.com themes with Drupal Twitter bootstrap

Tags: theming

I would like to know the easiest, simplest and quickest way to use anyone of the bootswatch.com free themes. There are some great themes there, better than I could spend a good 4+ hours trying to do. I'm merely looking to 'experiment' with CSS styles, swatches and the like. Can someone tell us how we can simply 'drag and drop'. I've tried what I thought it would be but it doesn't seem to do what I want it too, I'm not looking to spend hours on this, just to experiment with D7 for a few visual ideas. I have revieed the drupal.org Themeing documentation but that routed a little too long winded at this stage.

I appreciate there are some general paths that need changing in the CSS file and that JS needs to be correctly pointed to. My recent efforts only result in my backend Admin going a little wayout and I presume that simly 'deleting/over writing current CSS files in  the CSS folder isn't exactly the 'quick' way to do things. My long term reason is so I can have a number of preset themes to work with which I prefer and can quickly 'drag and drop' new theme ideas with outspending hours for something which is only for 'eye candy' visuals.

I would rather to it 'hand coding' style rather than a easy 'module' option for those why may suggest in advance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried this theme http://drupal.org/project/bootstrap. From what I can understand it must be what you are looking for

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If there's a solution that will let you apply any theme on top of twitter bootstrap just by dragging and dropping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the theme [bootstrap](http://drupal.org/project/bootstrap)

Download [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) place it in the bootstrap theme folder as mentioned in the theme page. Update jquery to 1.7 you might have to use the Jquery Update (Use the development version of JQuery Update and not the stable one as the development version has option to update it to 1.7. You can do that by going to admin -> jquery Update

By default the theme uses the bootstrap.css So you can simply replace that css file with the new one you download from [bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/) and you are good to go...

Comment: Thanks Mohammed, that is what I was hoping to hear from someone. Simply replacing the 'Twitter Bootstrap' with a CSS replacement of my choice, then renaming it to match the original (ie bootstrap.css) to be hooked by the system was what I meant by 'drag and drop'. I had been gearing towards your suggestion bu held back as some issues gave me thoughts on I was going down the wrong road. Any further advice on what other Drupalists do better to accomplish my original query is most welcome.

Comment: what kind of issues?

Comment: When I copied over to the CSS dir, the admin toolbar went missing. I presume I deleted a wrong CSS file or link from the .info or the edited path was incorrect, but put them right again. FYI, I'm working on an Ubuntu workstation editing using gedit and Aptana 3 for overall coding, but that my choice (-; I'll follow your advice as stated.

Comment: It appears that a number of links in my .info file were incorrect. I had an idea it may have been this but Mohammed's lead answer helped provide the result I needed. I resolved my issues by copying the said Bootswatch theme bootstrap.css into the said CSS directory for my Drupal theme and then checked that the stylesheet [all][] path linked to the correct file, saved the .info, cleared the cache and reloaded. The theme looks better now, but still needs a minor fix (such as Content page colours and the fact that my Admin Toolbar has gone!). But it is working now using a theme.

Comment: Just a point regarding the Menu Bar issues above (for future readers); if you find your backend Admin Menu Bar disappears or seems not right, check your jquery version. I was using the JQuery Update module and by mistake set it to 1.8, this caused issues, but was corrected once set to 1.5 in the JQuery Update module.

Answer (score 1):

Bundled these up together since I kept answering the same question for myself when implementing flavors of bootstrap -- https://github.com/btopro/bootswatch_drupal

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Normally, answers with just links in them aren't considered good ones.  Can you expand a little more about your GitHub project?

Comment: Thanks @user2108934 for the effort and share. Much appreciated for the work done.